# Convert into malayalama text in python 3.3.2

Tags: python

Hi, my code is like this(python 3.3.2)

```
fw = codecs.open('outputfile.txt','w')
if((unidata[i]==U'\u0d46' and unidata[i-1]==U'\u0d28') and (unidata[i+1]==U'\u0d24') and (unidata[i+2]==U'\u0d4d')):
    print ('code 1')
    if(var==1):
        x=unidata[0:i-1]+U'\u0d7b'+ ' + '+U'\u0d0e'+unidata[i+1:len(unidata)]
    first_word=unidata[0:i-1]+U'\u0d7b'
fw.write(str(first_word.encode('UTF-8')))
```

output in file is like this:

```
(b'\xe0\xb4\xb0\xe0\xb4\xbe\xe0\xb4\xae\xe0\xb5\xbb')
```

Actual output should be:

```
രാമൻ
```

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this works..

```
fw=open("myunicodefile.txt","w")
fw.write(firstword.encode('UTF-8'))
```

but i think you are telling about the strings inside the file####
yes actualy unicode will looks like that after converting using """"str()"""
    "\xe0\xb4\xb0\xe0\xb4\xbe\xe0\xb4\xae\xe0\xb5\xbb"

this is unicode.but to see this in malayalam with texteditor it must opened with uncode mode
*_*__and if you use python to read that file then must open that file and encode to utf

example:
    fr=open("mytext.txt","r")
    data=fr.read()
    unicodedata=data.encode("utf-8")
    print unicodedata

this will print malayalam

Comment: can you plz tell me,how can i visualize parse tree in python ,i have grammars..plz help me

Comment: hi ,can you please tell me..how to convert this hexa decimal form to malayalam [['\xe0\xb4\xb8\xe0\xb5\x80\xe0\xb4\xa4', '\xe0\xb4\xaf\xe0\xb5\x86']]

Answer (score 0):

[unicode deconversion issues and solutions](http://pythonhosted.org/kitchen/unicode-frustrations.html)

I'm giving the link bc they explain better than I can and theres additional definitions of functions there as well, number 3 on the directly linked page I think helps you though.